# How slow is * css selector for mobile browsers?

Tags: css, performance, mobile

How slow is the `*` css selector on mobile browsers?

Ive heard that it should't be used for speed reasons. However im mobile optimizing a site and I cant change the source code much at this point. I need to set `float:none, width:auto, height:auto, position:static` for a lot of elements. If I dont use `*` my selector list is going to get very long.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a long selector list. Many CSS resets already do this.

Comment: Can you use media queries to override instead?

Comment: Im using a media query within an existing global stylesheet. So is the * selector a bad choice?

Comment: It won't be so slow as to cause a FOUC or even a flash from desktop styles to mobile styles, at the very least.

Comment: using `*` isn't very good, just make a long selector list, thats fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a study out where this was tested. I no longer have the link but, suffice to say, it slows things down for all the reasons you probably know (every element needs to be evaluated).

As you may also already know, the different resets around choose and set only those elements that need 'resetting'. Some people, like myself, just set the elements to what we want them to be rather than a wholesale change.

Of course, like all things, testing it yourself is probably the best way.

Comment: [This](http://perfectionkills.com/profiling-css-for-fun-and-profit-optimization-notes/) article is a thorough look into CSS selector profiling and performance.